# How to reset deck of cards

Tags: c, arrays, loops, struct

I am making a game of Poker, and everything works perfectly, except I can not figure out how to get the deck to reset. Once I use all 52 cards the game crashes, and I can not figure out how to set the deck array back so that I can get a new set of 52 cards. This is what I have so far.

```
void shuffle(int wDeck[][13])
{
    int row = 0;    /* row number */
    int column = 0; /*column number */
    int card = 0;   /* card counter */
    int i = 0;

                    /* for each of the 52 cards, choose slot of deck randomly */
    for (card = 1; card <= 52; card++)
    {
        /* choose new random location until unoccupied slot found */
        do
        {
            row = rand() % 4;
            column = rand() % 13;
        } while (wDeck[row][column] != 0);

        /* place card number in chosen slot of deck */
        wDeck[row][column] = card;
    }
}
/* deal cards in deck */
Deck deal(const int wDeck[][13], const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[], Deck *cards)
{
    int row = 0;    /* row number */
    int column = 0; /*column number */
    int card = 0;   /* card counter */
    int i = 0, j = 5, k = 10;

                    /* deal each of the 52 cards */
    for (card = 1; card <= 52; card++)
    {
        /* loop through rows of wDeck */
        for (row = 0; row <= 3; row++)
        {
            /* loop through columns of wDeck for current row */
            for (column = 0; column <= 12; column++)
            {
                /* if slot contains current card, display card */
                if (wDeck[row][column] == card)
                {
                    //printf("%d) %5s of %-8s%c", card, wFace[column], wSuit[row], card % 4 == 0 ? '\n' : '\t');
                    cards->face[i] = column;
                    cards->suit[i] = row;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works for the beginning for the program, but once I use all 52 cards, I tried resetting them using these function

```
Deck replenish_deck(const int wDeck[][13], const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[], Deck *cards)
/*
This function will reshuffle and deal the deck if all 52 cards are used
*/
{
    int i = 0;
    if (cards->current_card == 52)
    {
        shuffle(wDeck);
        deal(wDeck, wFace, wSuit, cards);
    }
}
```

I tried putting a loop into the beginning of shuffle such as

```
for (row = 0; row < 4; row++)
{
    for (column = 0; column < 13; column++)
    {
        wDeck[row][column] = 0;
    }
}
```

But this just causes the names of the cards to mess up from the very beginning. Any help would be helpful. If you need more code that I did not provide, I will add it!

Comment: Where does it crash? That is the minimum info you should get before asking for help. The way to get that info (and much more) is to use a debugger.

Comment: Your "reset" loop will write to (among others) `wDeck[51][51]` which is likely well out of bounds.

Comment: The program itself crashes once all 52 cards are used. So I am trying to write code to restart the deck, which is where its messing up. debugger has not shown me anything except I need the deck[][] to be all 0 for the code to run or no card will be place @kaylum

Comment: `wDeck[i][i]` in the last loop shown, `i` goes up to 51. But your `wDeck` array second dimension is 13. And I don't believe your debugger shows "nothing" - at a minimum it will show you the exact line of code that triggers the crash. Learn to use the debugger effectively - it will be time well spent.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude programmer dude I changed my loop to the code above, and I out it in the beginning of the shuffle function, but the code still crashes once all the cards are used...

Comment: @kaylum I changed the loop, but it still crashes...

Comment: This is not productive. Use the debugger to find out exactly which line of code triggers the crash. Then look at the variable values on that line and proceed to debug further. You are going to get much further that way than trying to run Stackoverflow as a debugger.

Comment: It is important that we get a complete code in order to help you since all lines of  code are interdependent to each other.

Comment: "How to reset deck of cards" is a pretty bad name for a question.

Comment: Aside: please try to avoid magic numbers. In `for (column = 0; column <= 12; column++)` I guess that `12` is one less than the numbers of ranks in one suit, so the code would be clearer as `for (column = 0; column < 13; column++)` or even better with a `#define` or a `const int` so that the code is not sprinkled with `13` - let alone with `12` too. Suppose in another code you have, say, 8 rows and 8 columns and want to change it to 12 rows. Which of the hard-coded 8s would need to be edited?

Comment: The `deal()` and `replenish_deck()` functions have return type `Deck`, yet there is no `return` statement in either of these functions. If the code attempts to use a return value from one of these functions, you have undefined behavior.